# Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

"не_изученный"
Эффект плацебо – давно подмеченный, но не изученный процесс.

Comment: София, спасибо!

Comment: Если ответ нравится, Вы считаете его правильным, надо его принять - нажать на галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: Нажала) Спасибо)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это сопоставление с союзом НО,поэтому выбор свободный. Мы должны решить, отрицание это или утверждение.  Формально можно сделать замену: неизученный = неизвестный,  тогда пишем слитно: "Эффект плацебо – давно подмеченный, но неизученный процесс". Но это предложение звучит плохо: слитное написание причастия говорит о постоянном признаке, а это, скорее всего, не так. Значит, надо писать раздельно, чтобы подчеркнуть временной характер причастия. Поэтому пишем раздельно, а для себя делаем вывод: если форма неоднозначно передает содержание и вызывает у читателей вопросы, то эта форма не самая удачная. Лучше написать: "Эффект плацебо – давно подмеченный, но еще не изученный процесс". Тогда вопросов не будет: только раздельное написание (есть зависимое слово как временной показатель), да и смысл яснее. Можно предложить еще одну форму: "Эффект плацебо – давно подмеченный, но малоизученный  процесс". Но такие замены должны соответствовать той мысли, которую хочет выразить автор.

Comment: Полностью с Вами согласна. Слово ЕЩЁ просто просится в это предложение.

Answer (score 3):

Эффект плацебо – давно подмеченный, но неизученный процесс.

Здесь нет противопоставления. Оно было бы в примере "не изученный, а....". Это прилагательное, т.к. можно заменить синонимом "скрытый, тайный, таинственный", нет зависимых слов (например, никем не изученный, ещё не изученный), пишется слитно.

Comment: На написание прилагательных влияют не любые зависимые слова, а только отрицательные местоимения и наречия, а также сочетания "далеко не, вовсе не, отнюдь не". "Еще не изученный" - это у вас причастие получается.

Answer (score 0):

Эффект плацебо - эффект не изученный, а, пока, только подмеченный.    Здесь раздельно.